# Associating an obituary with a person on Ancestry

Tags: ancestry.com, obituary

This is what the burial and obituary look like in the facts section:

[image: Obit1]

The **burial** and **obituary** are both linked to the same source entry.

The **obituary** is a custom fact:

[image: Obit2]

I have attached the scan of the part of the **newspaper** to the **obituary** fact. And the **source** entry has the **transcription** of the actual newspaper.

Is this a satisfactory way to associate an obituary article with a person?

It is a pity that using the Ancestry app it doesn't seem to show the source transcription text:

[image: source in app]

Comment: I would consider an obituary as a source, not a fact.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl So you would have a source, associate the media with that source, and link it to burial?

Comment: Yes, but I'd link it not only to burial but to any other facts that it provided.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Ok.  I removed the fact, associated the media with the newspaper source and associated the death and burial facts. On the website the ancestry life story shows the obituary which is nice. iPad app doesn’t. Not to worry. Thank you.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl It's true that an Obituary is a source document, not a fact.  Nevertheless, Ancestry online trees allow us to pin documents to a person's profile on the tab which is called "Facts", and the Ancestry online tree system allows us to create 'Custom facts' for things which might not be facts.  I also use Custom Facts to create timeline placemarkers for newspaper articles.  Given all that, how can we improve this question?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl It might be worthwhile to consider how media items shared to Ancestry online trees from Newspapers.com and fold3, and custom 'facts' such as this one get treated when the tree is exported to GEDCOM or synced with RootsMagic or FTM. We could have Q/A about advantages & disadvantages of this approach.

Comment: @JanMurphy I haven't got any experience exporting or synching from Ancestry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been tracking genealogy for many many years (via TMG), and I'm new to using Ancestry.com. After reading posts like this and doing a little testing, I've decided to handle obits two ways. First, I'll attach a photo to the person if I have a scan or a screenshot of the obit. Second, I'll transcribe the obit to a simple Google Doc on my own account (simple if it's already on a website). Then on Ancestry.com, near the sources they have a place where you can add web links. I'm adding a link named "Obituary 1" that goes to the published obituary online (frequently from a newspaper or funeral home website), and another link named "Obituary 2" which goes to my own Google Doc. What I like about this approach is that I can easily get to the obit using either my computer or phone. And I also have a nice folder on my Google Drive with all of my obits in there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess there are many ways to do it. But I have not thought of Google Docs so I may investigate!